# How to pass a pointer to a static function as argument to another static function from inside a static function in C++

Tags: c++, static, function-pointers, argument-passing

How to pass a pointer to a static function as argument to another static function from inside a static function, which are all inside the same class? Im using VisualStudio 2010.
My code looks roughly like this:

```
//SomeClass.h
class SomeClass
{
    public:
        static AnotherClass* doSomething(AnotherClass*, AnotherClass*);
        static AnotherClass* doSomethingElse(AnotherClass*, AnotherClass*);

    private:
        typedef float (SomeClass::*SomeOperation)(float, float);
        static AnotherClass* apply(AnotherClass*, 
                                   AnotherClass*, 
                                   SomeOperation);

        static float SomeClass::operationA(float, float);
        static float SomeClass::operationB(float, float);
};

//SomeClass.cpp
AnotherClass* SomeClass::doSomething(AnotherClass* a, AnotherClass* b)
{
    return apply(a, b, &SomeClass::operationA);
}

AnotherClass* SomeClass::doSomethingElse(AnotherClass* a, AnotherClass* b)
{
    return apply(a, b, &SomeClass::operationB);
}

AnotherClass* apply(AnotherClass* a, 
                    AnotherClass* b, 
                    SomeOperation op)
{
    /* Some sanity checking and a lot of loop stuff which is the same
     * for all operations a, b, c ... */

}
```

I have tried different variants but keep getting compiler errors like:

C2664 "SomeClass::apply": conversion of parameter 3 from 'float (__cdecl *)(float, float)' in 'SomeClass::SomeOperation' not possible.

Has anyone an idea what I'm doing wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: I believe you want to switch to [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) which gives you [anonymous functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function) implemented with [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29). Consider upgrading your compiler: recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) -e.g. 4.8 or 4.9- is supporting C++11 quite well.

Comment: @Basile i.e. "use jQuery"?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: or perhaps "use Ocaml" or "use Common Lisp" ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A static member function is just a function; you don't use pointer to member syntax for it.

So instead of

```
typedef float (SomeClass::*SomeOperation)(float, float);
```

You want

```
typedef float (*SomeOperation)(float, float);
```

And you can just pass `operationA` rather than `&SomeClass::operationA`.

Comment: I'm accepting this one as the correct answer, because of the explanation why the "SomeClass::" part has to be omitted. Thanks again to everyone for the quick answers.

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
private:
    typedef float (SomeClass::*SomeOperation)(float, float);
```

To this:

```
public:
    typedef float (*SomeOperation)(float, float);
```

---

Or you can simply declare `typedef float (*SomeOperation)(float, float)` outside the class...

Answer (score 0):

Remove `SomeClass::` from the typedef.

There are a variety of syntax errors in the example, but after fixing them and doing that, I could compile your code.

Comment: Yes thats it tyvm! I'm not sure if its the VS2010 compiler or a general thing but I have another typdef for pointers to nonstatic methods at another point in the programm and there the "SomeClass::" is neccessary.